# How to implement certificate pinning on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, pinning

I know that this is not possibile on WP7 and WP8 but as i understoon the api to do this has been implemented on WP8.1 (Windows.Web.Http.Filters). But how can i use this system to check a ssl certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in WP7 (as you said) but possible using a [StreamSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226882) in WP8 as mentioned here:

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/4812599-support-ssl-certificate-pinning

You might also want to check out the [StreamSocket sample code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931)